# Moq: Exception to setup a mock with MockBehavior.Strict

Tags: moq

Is there a mechanism in Moq library to setup a particular method as Loose so that VerifyAll does not fail for that method.

```
[TestFixture]
public class MockStrictException
{
    [Test]
    public void exception_to_setup_strict()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<ITest>(MockBehavior.Strict);
        SetupAsPartOfTestSuite(mock);

        ITest subject = mock.Object;
        //Act
        subject.Called().Should().Be(10);

        mock.VerifyAll();
    }

    //Contrived example, however is actual usage there are setup helper methods
    //I understand it should not have been setup as strict 
    //but way too much effort to fix all test cases
    private static void SetupAsPartOfTestSuite(Mock<ITest> mock)
    {
        mock.Setup(x => x.Called()).Returns(10);
        //TODO: Is there a way to override this setup
        mock.Setup(x => x.NotCalled()).Returns(-10);
    }

    public interface ITest
    {
        int Called();
        int NotCalled();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Why not just set `MockBehavior.Loose` for this particular test? You already create the mock outside those helper functions.

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

```
 mock.Setup(x => x.Called()).Returns(10);
    //TODO: Is there a way to override this setup
    mock.Setup(x => x.NotCalled()).Returns(-10);
```

this would make sense if you made them verifiable by changing this to:

```
 mock.Setup(x => x.Called()).Returns(10).Verifiable();
 mock.Setup(x => x.NotCalled()).Returns(-10).Verifiable();
```

also why are you calling a strict behaviour? alternatively create a separate test method and verify them individually? Also I would suggest taking a brief look at [This Link Here](http://www.codethinked.com/beginning-mocking-with-moq-3-part-2) to better understand the verify of Moq.

A direct answer for your question is **no** Moq library does not contain a predefined way to create a loose class but im sure if you wanted to you could create you own as a helper extension.B